# Vue set wrong font url in css while packing multi-entries app

Tags: vue.js, webpack

- **PROBLEM DESCRIPTION**

I am using vue develop a multi-entries app, the project folder is some like:

```
|- assets
|  |- fonts
|  |  |- a.ttf  
|  |- styles
|  |  |- b.css     // import ../fonts/a.ttf
|- src
|  |- page_one
|  |  |- App.vue   // import ../../assets/styles/b.css
```

Above project runs well in local deleopment enviroment, but reported 404 for the `.ttf` resource after deployed on the server. I checked the built product, found that the css font url is incorrect: I got `http://<host>/css/fonts/a.ttf`, while `http://<host>/fonts/a.ttf` is the expected URL.

- **TRACK the CAUSE**

After lots of survey, I found above problem is **related to the page entry**. Since I got a lot pages, and I wanted to separate them into different folders, so the entries are some like:

```
// vue.config.js
module.exports = {
  pages: {
    'a/one': {
      filename: 'a/one.html',
    },
  },
};
```

After built, the folder is like:

```
|- dist
|  |- css
|  |  |- a
|  |  |  |- one-<hash>.css // import ../fonts/a.ttf
|  |- fonts
|  |  |- a.ttf
```

- **ROOT REASON**: The pack tool (webpack) output css file in subfoler `a/one-<hash>.css`, while the url in css file is incorrect. Looks webpack supposed css file is directly placed at css folder.
- **SOLUTION**: **DO NOT USE `/` IN ENTRY**. A correct configuration file is like:

```
// vue.config.js
module.exports = {
  pages: {
    'a-one': { // JUST DO NOT USE SLASH.
      filename: 'a/one.html', // You can use this to build the produced pages intro separate folders
    },
  },
};
```

After all, if you use webpack and meet same problem, the reason and solution should be same.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the '/' from the page entry. Correct:

```
// vue.config.js
module.exports = {
  pages: {
    'a-one': { // JUST DO NOT USE SLASH.
      filename: 'a/one.html', // You can use this to build the produced pages intro separate folders
    },
  },
};
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).